# Order of code to get superscript in front of letter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph where I want the x-axis label to read 206Pb/207Pb with the numbers in superscript. I can't get it to work unless the numbers are coming after the word 'Pb'. Does anyone know how to get them to come in front and preferably with the backslash in between too?

Thanks.

```
p1<-ggplot(waplead, aes(x =Pb206207 , y = Depth))+
  labs(y = "Depth (cm)")+
  geom_lineh(size=1.1)+
  geom_errorbarh((aes(xmin=Pb206207-Pb206207Error, xmax=Pb206207+Pb206207Error)))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3,fill="#FFFFFF")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_reverse(limits=c(50,0),breaks=seq(0,50,5))+
  xlab(bquote(' '~ '' ~~ Pb^206~Pb^207*''))



p1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `expression`

```
p1<-ggplot(waplead, aes(x =Pb206207 , y = Depth))+
    geom_lineh(size=1.1)+
    geom_errorbarh((aes(xmin=Pb206207-Pb206207Error, xmax=Pb206207+Pb206207Error)))+
    geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3,fill="#FFFFFF")+
    theme_classic()+
    scale_y_reverse(limits=c(50,0),breaks=seq(0,50,5))+
    labs(x=expression(paste(""^{206}~Pb~"/"^{207}~Pb)),
         y="Depth (cm)")
p1
```